# What is the use of destructuring in a generic declaration?

Tags: typescript, generics, apollo

Destructuring might be the wrong term...

Found this in the codebase I'm working in. It's perplexing.

```
await apolloClient
    .query<{ Workorder: Workorder }>({
      query: WORKORDER_QUERY,
      variables: { uuid: id },
    })
```

I don't see the point of `{ Workorder: Workorder }`. What is happening here? What is the value of that vs `.query<Workorder>`?

`Workorder` is an interface with about 30 properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not destructuring. It just means that the type argument being passed is an object with a Workorder property, and that the value for that property is a Workorder.

For example, given:

```
type Workorder = { order: boolean };
declare function fn<T>(): T;

const result = fn<Workorder>();
```

where the type parameter is the same type that's returned, the `result` is of type:

```
{
  order: boolean
}
```

Whereas if you do

```
const result = fn<{ Workorder: Workorder }>();
```

the result is now of the type:

```
{
  Workorder: {
    order: boolean
  }
}
```

Not that `.query` does the same thing, but that'll give you an idea of what the difference is. Doing `<{ Workorder: Workorder }>` just wraps the Workorder in an object and passes it as a type parameter.

Comment: What is the value of that vs `.query<Workorder>`?

Comment: It's `{ order: boolean }` vs `{ Workorder: { order: boolean }}` Nothing special, it's just wrapping it in another object

Comment: it seems like it would be much more readable if the `Workorder` was in the variables object of the input